# Which is a more efficient integer array size in Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management

Okay, so I'm working on a custom data structure which uses a fairly large number of arrays to efficiently stored a lot (millions of entries) efficiently, but I got to wondering; what is the most efficient way to size the arrays?

My natural inclination is to pick array sizes using binary powers, e.g - sizes of 4, 8, 16 etc., but since Java arrays also include their length, should I count that as if it were an additional element, i.e - if I'm storing an array of integers, should I be using sizes of 3, 7, 15 etc. instead, to account for the extra integer?

I realise for most cases this is probably academic, but selecting new array sizes is already its own function in my code, so it'd be dead easy to tweak, plus I'm interested to know.

Comment: if you don't use full of your array in all case then use `ArrayList` to resize when required

Comment: Is this academic? Because in real-life scenarios you're just wasting your time building custom data structure backed by arrays. Java already provides `ArrayList` to serve the same purpose.

Comment: "*My natural inclination is to pick array sizes using binary powers*" => what makes you think that it is efficient to do that?

Comment: Define 'efficiently'.  What will be more efficient in terms of runspeed is to allocate everything you might possibly need up front so you don't have to copy arrays on resize, but that's very *inefficient* in terms of storage.

Comment: You should avoid using static array when the size needed is arbitrary. You don't you use ArrayList?

Comment: @assylias Probably historical inertia from languages where memory allocation in powers of two (and subsequent deallocation) might make better use of the available space (e.g., `malloc`).  Also, reallocation is often done by doubling the previous size, which has nice amortization properties (resizes per insert), and since that's doubling, people might associate it with binary powers (though it's not quite for the same reason, and doesn't produce the same sizes, unless the initial size was a power of two).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Memory allocation with respect to cache line bounaries does offer a small performance advantage, and cache lines are usually a power of two sized. Its somewhat difficult to do in practice, since memory granularity of the allocator is usually quite fine (4 or 8 bytes), and one would need not only to properly control size, but also alignment. It could be done by allocation a little more memory (lines size - granularity bytes) and adjusting the resulting pointer from malloc to the next cache line boundary.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In case you or someone else is not aware, *doubling* the size on re-allocation is not necessary, it's just the simplest option (the smallest integer > 1). The amortization works just as well for *any* constant **factor**.

Comment: @delnan Indeed.  I was just pointing out that some old advice and (a bit of distortion about) some common practice could put the "power of two" idea into someone's head.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's good that you're describing the various ways such misconceptions may arise, but I think it would be more helpful (especially for OP) to mention *why this is a misconception* at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked basically the same question here: [Determine the optimal size for array with respect to the JVM's memory granularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222296) (but got no useful responses)

The main problem in chosing the *perfect* array size is that it requires knowledge how the VM actually lays out an array in memory, and can't be pre-determined because it depends a lot on platform architecture, but also VM version and possibly VM *parameters* (e.g. Compressed OOP on/off with 64-bit).

You could look up the granularity for typical VM settings though or simply hardcode reasonable assumptions into your array size selection.

Edit: There is a solution, but its not portable (using Unsafe class): http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/

Comment: Thanks @Durandal and @delnan, this is the kind of information I was hoping for. For those that were asking why I don't just use an `ArrayList`; the answer is that I have to operate upon and re-order chunks of data, I tried using various configurations of ArrayList and the performance was just horrible, but with larger numbers of (relatively) smaller arrays I'm wary that I may be introducing a lot of overhead so could tweak my sizes to reduce that.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the array size affects is when the array is full. Unlike for example hash tables, where you frequently need to perform modulo operations (which can be optimized if you know that the size is a power of two), an ordinary array only needs to *compare* the size, and comparison is uniformly fast for all values.

Different initial capacities and different growth factors might nevertheless affect program performance or memory consumption, but only because some growth patterns "fit" some uses better, in that they better balance the space wasted on over-allocation and the time for resizing (both are amortized O(1), but still subject to hidden constant factors). However, this depends entirely on how a *typical* program behaves on *typical* inputs. It's not something you can decide in isolation by staring at the array implementation.

In the absence of more data, you should just pick an arbitrary but reasonable starting capacity (somewhere between 1 and 30 I'd say) and growth factors (somewhere between 1.5 and 3 I'd say). At worst it decreases performance by a constant factor, and a rather small one at that. Or let the user pick it, if you want to make the API slightly more complicated.

Comment: "The only thing the array size affects is when the array is full" It might not make much difference in Java, but the size of blocks of memory allocated and deallocated can have effects.  There's a reason that memory in C is often allocated in sizes that are powers of two, for instance.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It depends very much on the internals of the memory allocator, and even when it has any effect the only effect is the allocation size being rounded up and some memory being wasted. But unless your allocator is exceptionally sensitive to these things (many opt not to be because a lot of code *doesn't* go for power of two blocks), the waste is at worst one page (4 KiB) which is peanuts.

Comment: Agreed, I'm just pointing out that the idea that OP has isn't entirely unfounded.  There's historical precedent for allocation in powers of 2, so it's possible that OP heard some advice that probably doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: Joshua, The reason you do this in C is because C does not have automatic memory management. In Java the size of your array is irrelevant, because it is not allocated dynamically (unless you're out of heap space, and you've configured your heap to grow). If this is truly academic, then the most efficient array size is likely to be "Any number smaller than your L1 cache", if it's a real problem, then you may need to switch to off-heap allocation, so you get the same degree of control (and headaches) over memory you get in C, if it's a case of premature optimization, it's best not to worry.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke What do you mean "not allocated dynamically"? It's not delegated to the OS or libc, and the deallocation happens automatically, but it's still dynamic memory management. And the scenarios in which power-of-two sizes matter in C are related only to the internals of how the memory manager tracks which regions of RAM are allocated and which aren't, which is entirely language-agnostic and also necessary in the innards of a JVM.

Comment: @delnan, I mean it's "allocated" on the heap, and so not "allocated" in the way you would usually understand the concept if you were a C programmer. And while yes, if you were writing your own JVM, that would indeed be relevant, as a Java application programmer, it's not, unless as mentioned previously you are using off-heap memory.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I really don't know what you are talking about, please be more precise. It's allocated in exactly the same sense, and the ramifications of allocation sizes, if they exist, are also the same. The perspective of someone writing their own JVM is comparable to the perspective of someone writing their own memory allocator in C, but nobody's talking about that. The question is simply `T *a = new T[n]` versus `T[] a= new T[n]`.

Comment: When you create a new array in Java you are not allocating a new memory block, it is "reserved" on the heap, which you have almost no control over. If you want that degree of control, you need to use off-heap allocation. If that is not clear enough, then I can't help you further. Other than that, thank you for reiterating my point.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke You seem to be using a very peculiar definition of "allocation". Of course you are allocating a new memory block. Reserving part of the available memory is pretty much synonymous to memory allocation. Note that a C program also has zero control over which part of the available memory it's being handed. And control over *when* it's returned/deallocated has no effect whatsoever on the things this question, answer and comment thread have been about so far.

Comment: Like I've already said, if you don't understand how allocating memory on the JVM heap (which has already been allocated though to OS/MMU) is inherently different than simply asking the OS/MMU for a block of protected memory, then I can't think of further ways to explain it to you. And thank you for reiterating the point I made in my very first post. All this time, were you just being deliberately obtuse?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55986/discussion-between-delnan-and-mikkel-lokke).